# Centralizar texto e mudar cor JSP CSS

Tags: html, css, css3, jsp

Gostaria de colocar os meus itens do meu menu no centro e muda-los de cor, no caso colocar uma cor branca mas não estou conseguindo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
 #menu{
            background-color:#6495ED;


        }
        .conteudo{
              display:inline;
            text-align: center;  
            padding: 10px;
             color:white;

        }
         <nav id="menu">

        <div class="conteudo"> <a href="index.jsp">Pagina Principal</a>
       </div>
        <div class="conteudo"> <a href="produtos.jsp">Produtos</a></div>
        <div class="conteudo"><a href="contato.jsp">Contato</a></div>
     </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
 #menu{
          background-color:#6495ED;
          text-align: center;
          padding: 10px !important;
        }
        .conteudo{
            display: inline;
        }
        a {
          padding: 10px !important;
          text-decoration: none;
          color: white;
        }
```

```html
<nav id="menu">
        <div class="conteudo"> <a href="index.jsp">Pagina Principal</a>
       </div>
        <div class="conteudo"> <a href="produtos.jsp">Produtos</a></div>
        <div class="conteudo"><a href="contato.jsp">Contato</a></div>
     </nav>
```

Answer (score -2):

Para centralizar os itens do menu utilize:

```
text-align: center;
```

E para mudar a cor:

```
color: #ffffff;
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).